# How to make a Profile picture inside a sliverappbar that expands in flutter

Tags: flutter, sliverappbar, flutter-sliverappbar

I need a sort of Avatar photo widget that when I scroll down it transforms into a circle having the user name next to it and when I scroll back up, it becomes big and shows the user name under it, just like older versions of the Samsung contacts app.